# django template change behaviour to silent_variable_failure = False

Tags: django, django-templates

http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter10/

"Note that django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist, which is the base class for all Django database API DoesNotExist exceptions, has silent_variable_failure = True. So if you’re using Django templates with Django model objects, any DoesNotExist exception will fail silently."

Whilst I'm developing I'd like to reverse this behaviour, i.e. silent_variable_failure = False.  How do I make this change permanent whilst developing under django ?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In settings.py I added
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = "invalid string '%s'"
See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables for more info.

It includes this warning
"Many templates, including those in the Admin site, rely upon the silence of the template system when a non-existent variable is encountered. If you assign a value other than '' to TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID, you will experience rendering problems with these templates and sites."

Comment: In django 1.8 the `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` [has changed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33750585/1888983). See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/#the-templates-settings).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the question?

Answer (score 1):

The Django template system looks for `silent_variable_failure` as an attribute of any exception.

This means you have do define your own exception with that attribute set to `False`.

For the standard `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception generated by the ORM, etc., the simplest solution would be to modify the Django sourcecode on your development box (django/core/exceptions.py).

If this was something you needed to change on a production system then you would need to 1) define your own exception class, 2) put a manager on your model that is called from the template (instead of using ORM methods directly), and then 3) catch DoesNotExist in your manager and re-raise the exception with your own class.

Comment: Thanks for the good info.  I edited /usr/share/python-support/python-django/django/core/exceptions.py and changed to silent_variable_failure = False but i could not get the behaviour to change.  Not sure if I needed to regenerate .pyc file.  I deleted /var/lib/python-support/python2.6/django/core/exceptions.pyc in desperation but to no avail.

I think TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID will do what I want, maybe the behaviour is different in later version of django. I'm running Django version 1.0.2 final

Answer (score -1):

Another setting, TEMPLATE_DEBUG, can be set to True in settings.py to alter this behavior.

Comment: No. TEMPLATE_DEBUG makes some things better, but not this.