# How to see exception generated into django template variable?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Inside a Django template, one can call an object method like this :

```
{{ my_object.my_method }}
```

The problem is when you get an exception/bug in 'def my_method(self)', it is hidden when rendering the template (there is an empty string output instead, so no errors appears).

As I want to debug what's wrong in 'def my_method(self)', I would like to turn on something like a global django flag to receive such exception.

in settings.py, I already have

```
DEBUG = True 
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
```

I can receive many kind of template exceptions, but none when I trig an object method.

What can I do ?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem... I would consider this a bug in django itself...

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables

Answer (score 16):

Here's a nice trick I just implemented for doing exactly this.   Put this in your debug settings:

```
class InvalidString(str):
    def __mod__(self, other):
        from django.template.base import TemplateSyntaxError
        raise TemplateSyntaxError(
            "Undefined variable or unknown value for: %s" % other)

// this option is deprecated since django 1.8
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = InvalidString("%s")

// put it in template's options instead
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        // ...
        'OPTIONS': {
             'string_if_invalid': InvalidString("%s"),
        },
    },
]
```

This will cause a TemplateSyntaxError to be raised when the parses sees an unknown or invalid value.  I've tested this a little (with undefined variable names) and it works great.  I haven't tested with function return values, etc.  Things could get complicated.

Comment: Clever!  This is probably going to give a lot of false positives, but it's a really good approach.

Comment: A clever hack. It's too bad Django doesn't provide this functionality out of the box. No, this won't cause any "false positives".

Comment: It'd be fantastic if this worked but it doesn't seem to do anything for me. Using django 1.8.

Comment: (I just updated this answer for newer django versions.)

Answer (score 3):

Finally I Found a solution: I developed a template debug tag :

```
from django import template
import traceback

class DebugVariable(template.Variable):
    def _resolve_lookup(self, context):
        current = context
        for bit in self.lookups:
            try: # dictionary lookup
                current = current[bit]
            except (TypeError, AttributeError, KeyError):
                try: # attribute lookup
                    current = getattr(current, bit)
                    if callable(current):
                        if getattr(current, 'alters_data', False):
                            current = settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
                        else:
                            try: # method call (assuming no args required)
                                current = current()                            
                            except:
                                raise Exception("Template Object Method Error : %s" % traceback.format_exc())
                except (TypeError, AttributeError):
                    try: # list-index lookup
                        current = current[int(bit)]
                    except (IndexError, # list index out of range
                            ValueError, # invalid literal for int()
                            KeyError,   # current is a dict without `int(bit)` key
                            TypeError,  # unsubscriptable object
                            ):
                        raise template.VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key [%s] in %r", (bit, current)) # missing attribute
                except Exception, e:
                    if getattr(e, 'silent_variable_failure', False):
                        current = settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
                    else:
                        raise
            except Exception, e:
                if getattr(e, 'silent_variable_failure', False):
                    current = settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
                else:
                    raise

        return current

class DebugVarNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = DebugVariable(var)

    def render(self, context):
        return self.var.resolve(context)

@register.tag('debug_var')
def do_debug_var(parser, token):
    """
    raise every variable rendering exception, TypeError included (usually hidden by django)

    Syntax::
        {% debug_var obj.my_method %} instead of {{ obj.my_method }}        
    """
    bits = token.contents.split()
    if len(bits) != 2:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("'%s' tag takes one argument" % bits[0])
    return DebugVarNode(bits[1])
```

So now in my template I just replace

```
{{ my_object.my_method }} by {% debug_var my_object.my_method %}
```

Answer (score 2):

`TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` doesn't work for me. A quick fix is to open `env/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py`, find `except Exception` and throw a `print e` inside it (assuming you're using `manage.py runserver` and can see print output).

However, a few lines down is `current = context.template.engine.string_if_invalid`. I noticed `string_if_invalid` was empty despite having set `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID`. This lead me to this part of the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/#the-templates-settings

> Django’s template system was overhauled in Django 1.8 when it gained support for multiple template engines.
>
> ...
>
> If your settings module defines `ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS` or `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID`, include their values under the '`allowed_include_roots`' and '`string_if_invalid`' keys in the '`OPTIONS`' dictionary.

So in addition to [@slacy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854378/1888983) TemplateSyntaxError trick,

> ```
> class InvalidString(str):
>     def __mod__(self, other):
>         from django.template.base import TemplateSyntaxError
>         raise TemplateSyntaxError(
>             "Undefined variable or unknown value for: %s" % other)
>
> TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = InvalidString("%s")
> ```

you also need to define `string_if_invalid` as follows

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'string_if_invalid': TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID,
            ...
```

---

Straight away this found a bunch of issues I had I didn't even know about. It really should be enabled by default. To solve tags and filters that expect to fail silently I threw conditionals around them:

```
{% if obj.might_not_exist %}
{{ obj.might_not_exist }}
{% endif %}
```

Although I suspect this only works because the `{% if %}` fails silently. Another approach might be to create a `hasattr` filter: `{% if obj|hasattr:"might_not_exist" %}`.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do ?

Evaluate the exception-generating method in your view function.

```
def someView( request ):
    .... all the normal work ...

    my_object.my_method() # Just here for debugging.

    return render_to_response( ... all the normal stuff... )
```

You can remove that line of code when you're done debugging.

Comment: I already use this method, it's quite boring : there is really no flag into django to raise variable exception ??

Comment: @Eric: "boring"?  Sorry that work is boring you.  Perhaps you should find another job.  Seriously.  Unit tests will work better than this.  Finding an exception in a template means you failed to debug your model and your view functions using proper unit tests.  You don't need to find exceptions in the template because there are **better** ways which are simpler, more reliable and easier to debug.  Sorry that it's boring.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a [Unit tests](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/) to isolate the problem. I know this is an indirect answer but I feel this is the ideal way to solve and prevent the problem from returning.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to S. Lott's answer, activate the management shell (python manage.py shell) and create the appropriate instance of my_object, call my_method. Or put exception handling in my_method and log the exception.