# Calling a function in a Django template, why it doesnt return anything?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This is a function in a `Django 1.5` model:

```
def expirationdate(self):
        start = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.premiumactivation,'%Y-%m-%d')
        expiration = start + datetime.timedelta(days=self.premiumduration)
        return expiration
```

called by this template:

```
{% if view_user_profile.premiumstatus %}
    <p>You are a premium user from: {{ view_user_profile.premiumactivation }}</p>
    <p>Your premium subscription will expire: {{ view_user_profile.expirationdate }}</p>
{% else %}
    <p>You are not a premium user yet! Buy your premium account <a href="/premium/">here!</p>
{% endif %}
```

The `if` condition works, because I can see `view_user_profile.expirationdate`.
The function `expirationdate`, however, do not return anything. I tred `return 'error message'` just to be sure and even that isn't showed.

I already called other fucntions with this syntax so I'm really stuck.

Comment: If `print expiration` inside `expirationdate` before the `return`, do you see the value you are expecting when you render the template?

Answer (score 0):

If I write it like this works:

```
def expirationdate(self):
    expiration = self.premiumactivation + datetime.timedelta(days=self.premiumduration)
    return expiration
```

I'm not really sure why but I will not complain.

Comment: If that works and your first posted version doesn't, it seems apparent to me that `self.premiumactivation` is already a `date` or `datetime` object and does not need to have `strptime` called on it to convert it. This would make sense if `premiumactivation` is a `DateField` or `DateTimeField` on the model. As for why it doesn't show up in the template - calling `strptime` on a `date` instance will raise an exception, and the Django template engine writes no output for methods that raised exceptions unless you set TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID.

Comment: See this answer for a clever trick to put more exception information into TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305948/how-to-see-exception-generated-into-django-template-variable